# Javascript debugger in eclipse environment

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse-plugin, zend-debugger

How can I install one without the all environment stop working?

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Use the developer tools (including debugger) in Chorme — or the Firebug plugin for Firefox.

What you can do is set up Chrome or Firefox in `Run` → `External tools` to easily test your code in them. See here:

- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-browser-window-via-eclipse.html?page=1